# Setting value to item from Spinner

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner

So i created a Spinner and set 5 values in it.
I'm building a calculator and want to every item from Spinner have some value (they have text value, but I want them to have number value). Before that, user has to enter his TDEE, don't bother with that, it's just a number, and that number then multiplys with value of selected spinner item. That all happends when the button is clicked, and then the value prints down in text view.

The problem is, I don't have idea how to pass values to spinner items.

Here's the code:

Strings:

```
<string-array name="razina_aktivnosti">
        <item>Sjedeći (Malo ili bez aktivnosti, pretežno sjedeći posao)</item>
        <item>Laka aktivnosti (Lake vježbe/sport 1-3 dana tjedno)</item>
        <item>Umjeren (Umjerene vježbe/sport 3-5 dana tjedno)</item>
        <item>Teške aktivnosti (Teže vježbe/sport 6-7 dana tjedno)</item>
        <item>Ekstremne aktivnosti (Teške dnevne vježbe/sport i fizički posao 2 x dnevno)</item>

    </string-array>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.KalkulatoriTDEE"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_kalkulatori_tdee">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout22"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Unesite svoj BMR:"
            android:id="@+id/textView115" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editBMRInput" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout22"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout23"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Odaberite razinu aktivnosti"
                android:id="@+id/aktivnost"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout22"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerTDEE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/aktivnost"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout23">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Izračunaj"
            android:id="@+id/btnIzracunajTDEE"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#424242"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Vaš TDEE je:"
            android:id="@+id/textView116"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/textViewRezultatTDEE"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
package hr.app.liftme.liftmehr;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class KalkulatoriTDEE extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    Button btnIzracunaj;
    EditText editBMRInput;
    TextView textViewRezultat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kalkulatori_tdee);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = getIntent();





        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTDEE);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.razina_aktivnosti, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        btnIzracunaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIzracunajTDEE);

        editBMRInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBMRInput);

        textViewRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRezultatTDEE);

        btnIzracunaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                double prvoPolje = Double.parseDouble(editBMRInput.getText().toString());
                // HERE'S WHERE I'VE STUCKED!!!

                double rezultat = 0;



                btnIzracunaj.setText(Double.toString(rezultat));
            }
        });


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)+" selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }


        });



    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to **set** the values of the Spinner? Or retrieve the values **from** the Spinner?

Comment: Spinner has 5 values that are set in strings.xml. I want to when for example first item from the Spinner is selected that I can multiply it with that double prvoPolje

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getSelectedItem()` from the [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html):

```
spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

So, in your code replace your `btnIzracunaj` listener with:

```
btnIzracunaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

You are going to have to parse what you have on your **strings.xml**. I would recommend you to set them as numbers just to test:

```
<string-array name="razina_aktivnosti">
  <item>1.1</item>
  <item>2.2</item>
  <item>3.3</item>
  <item>4.4</item>
  <item>5.5</item>
</string-array>
```

---

**Edit:**

With your **strings.xml** set with only floating numbers, your new onClickListener would look like:

```
btnIzracunaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        double prvoPolje = Double.parseDouble(editBMRInput.getText().toString());
        double rezultat = 0;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        rezultat = Double.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        btnIzracunaj.setText(String.valueOf(rezultat * prvoPolje));
    }
});
```

Comment: Well it does not crashes so that's a good thing. But i want text to be represented instead of numbers, and for the first item in Spinner I wan't it to have value of 1.2. How to do that?

Comment: OK, after that edit multiplication works fine, but sill I want the text